# web3.eth.getAccounts() gets no accounts

Tags: metamask, web3-providers

I got no accounts loaded with code

```
import Web3 from "web3";

let web3;

// typeof check if variable exists
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {

    web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
    console.log("Metamask used");
    const getAccounts = async () => {
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        return accounts;
    };

    console.log('first account is ', getAccounts()[0]);
} else {
    console.log('not Metamask');
    const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
        'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/foo'
    );
    web3 = new Web3(provider);
}

export default web3;
```

And I got console log:

```
Metamask used
first account is `undefined`
```

So I can assume `metamask` is injected in the `window`, however no accounts were loaded. (I absolutely had logged in my metamask)

Version:

```
"next": "^4.1.4",
"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.35"
```

Have someone encountered the same problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest to upgrade web3 to version 1.2.x. Did you call `ethereum.enable()`? Unless your site is approved by the user `getAccounts` will return nothing. See metamask docs https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#connecting-to-metamask.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getAccounts` function returns a `Promise` object, not an array of accounts.

So the expression `getAccounts()[0]` is obviously `undefined`.

You'll need to resolve that promise in order to retrieve the actual array.

For example, using `const accounts = await getAccounts();` from inside an `async` function.

Comment: hi, goodvib. Should I add another async function below like async () => {await getAccounts()} ?